# How to get current day count of the quarter

Tags: javascript

I used the below approach to get quarter of the given date.

```
const month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
const quarter = Math.ceil(month/3);
```

Now I want to get current day count of the quarter. Ex. Current Date is 2018 Jun 20, the I want the current day of the quarter is 81. How can I achieve it? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: in Javascript please

Comment: the other question contains the logic, all you need to do is to write it in javascript. I assume the logic is what you need to solve this

Comment: Use [JavaScript : How to Calculate number of days between two dates using javascript](//stackoverflow.com/q/9129928) to get the number of days since the beginning of the quarter.

Comment: it is in moment.js, But I need in full Javascript please.

Comment: Thanks Shubam Khatri. I changed to Javascript and it is working fine.